# Test whether the point is between matching quotes (emacs lisp)

Tags: emacs, lisp, quotes, point

How do we check whether `(point)` is within matching "quotes"

Example 1: "`(point)`",

but not within

Example 2: "quote here" `(point)` "quote there",

in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: The only way I can see to be able to do it is to check for the font-lock attached, but then how does the font lock know? Maybe functions from C. Would it be the only option to do a font check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is `syntax-ppss` (defined in `syntax.el`).
It returns 10 values, and the 4th tells you whether the point is inside a string.

Comment: To summarize, `(nth 3 (syntax-ppss))` is a nice concise way to check this based on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`(eq (nth 1 (text-properties-at (point))) font-lock-string-face)`

This checks whether the font of the text at point is recognized as a string (i.e. has the text property face font-lock-string-face).

This looking for a more elegant solution.