# Color variables inside parenthesis

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently transitioned from vim to emacs and miss one key feature of shell scripting: variables being highlighted inside double quotes. How do I put this feature back in?

I read [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078322/test-whether-the-point-is-between-matching-quotes-emacs-lisp) that you can use `syntax-ppss` to detect interior of quotes, but how do I actually change the color?

Note that the colors should be turned on for: `name="$first $last"` but NOT for `name='$first $last'`

Comment: Most programming modes already highlight `"..."` as strings, regardless of what is between the `"` marks. And that is typically done using [syntactic font lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntactic-Font-Lock.html), which generally overrides use of `font-lock-keywords`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, this exact question was [asked and answered](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13128) in emacs.stackexchange.com just a couple of days ago:

The code below use a font-lock rule with a function instead of a regexp, the function search for occurrences of `$VAR` but only when they are inside a double-quoted string. The function `(syntax-ppss)` is used to determine this.

The font-lock rule use the `prepend` flag to add itself on top of the existing string highlighting. (Note that many packages use `t` for this. Unfortunately, this overwrites all aspects of the existing highlighting. For example, using `prepend` will retain a string background color (if there is one) while replacing the foreground color.)

```
(defun sh-script-extra-font-lock-is-in-double-quoted-string ()
  "Non-nil if point in inside a double-quoted string."
  (let ((state (syntax-ppss)))
    (eq (nth 3 state) ?\")))

(defun sh-script-extra-font-lock-match-var-in-double-quoted-string (limit)
  "Search for variables in double-quoted strings."
  (let (res)
    (while
        (and (setq res
                   (re-search-forward
                    "\\$\\({#?\\)?\\([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\\|[-#?@!]\\)"
                    limit t))
             (not (sh-script-extra-font-lock-is-in-double-quoted-string))))
    res))

(defvar sh-script-extra-font-lock-keywords
  '((sh-script-extra-font-lock-match-var-in-double-quoted-string
     (2 font-lock-variable-name-face prepend))))

(defun sh-script-extra-font-lock-activate ()
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil sh-script-extra-font-lock-keywords)
  (if (fboundp 'font-lock-flush)
      (font-lock-flush)
    (when font-lock-mode
      (with-no-warnings
        (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))))
```

You can call use this by adding the last function to a suitable hook, for example:

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook 'sh-script-extra-font-lock-activate)
```

Comment: Yea I saw that but then couldn't find it when I searched again. Thanks!